# Можно ли на PHP/JS/JQuery с имитировать наведение мыши на элемент?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте. Стоит задача спарсить страницу, но прежде, чем забирать её DOM, нужно её несколько модифицировать. Дело в том, что на странице все ссылки обернуты тегом `<span>` и только после наведения на этот элемент они преобразуются в тег `<a>`
Код, решающий эту проблему, выглядит примерно следующим образом:

```
$("tr > td > div > div.bus-point > div > span").mouseenter().mouseleave();
```

Т.е. сначала мне нужно попасть на страницу, выполнить эту команду и только после этого забрать DOM страницы.
Подскажите, возможно ли это вообще, и если возможно, как это реализовать?
Заранее благодарен всем отозвавшимся.

Comment: При наведении на тег `<span>`, откуда беруться данные для тега `<a>`. Например, `href` откуда возьмется?

Comment: Вобще, тег span выглядит вот таким образоом: <span class="master-lnk" data-a="!aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuYXZ0b3Zva3phbHkucnUvcmFzcGlzYW5pZS9tb3NrdmEvc2NoZWxrb3Zv" title="Москва - Щелковский автовокзал (Центральный): подробная информация: адрес, телефон">Щелковский автовокзал (Центральный)<br></span> Ну а как из него генерируется ссылка, javascript на странице как-то за это отвечает

Comment: @lost а что, взять `span` и его атрибуты и переконвертить на своей стороне это в ссылку религия не позволяет?   Посмотрите тот же JS как там преобразуется ссылка. Или это проблемно открыть консоль и ресурсы браузера?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не издевайтесь. У всех разные уровни знаний. @lost. А Вам, похоже, надо собрать все тэги **<span>** и у них взять атрибут `data-a`, в нем хранится ссылка `href` тега **<a>**, на который преобразуется **<span>** в браузере.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko большое спасибо за понимание. Я думал над тем, чтобы на своей стороне конвертить span в ссылку, но так и не нашел, каким образом это выполняется на их стороне.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел решение.

```
data-a="!aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuYXZ0b3Zva3phbHkucnUvcmFzcGlzYW5pZS9‌​tb3NrdmEvc2NoZWxrb3Z‌​v"
```

Декодируется функцией `base64_decode()`. Огромное спасибо всем откликнувшимся.